# Single-step Monte Carlo in Excel

Tags: monte-carlo, excel

How do you simulate correctly using raw prices not returns?

I have corresponding periods of earnings to Futures but the Excel call function =NORMINV(RAND(),mean,stdev) generates negative Futures prices?

Ignoring stationarity issues, how to create a random variable of positive integers?

Comment: By earnings, do you mean Profit&Loss ?

Comment: Yes, net earnings/income.

Comment: Quick tip - if you only have 1 time step, then for you first dimension, equally space your "random" numbers between 0 and 1 (ie 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,...). It hugely reduces the variance.

Comment: Very interesting tip, @will. What do you mean by dimension? How do we partition a time-step even further - thought it is the base intervals length?

Comment: Be aware that Excel's RAND() function is very poor.  See discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891165/is-excel-vbas-rnd-really-this-bad

Answer (score 2):

The code below is part of a VBA project I did to calculate VaR with Monte Carlo returns.  If you eliminate the `-1` at the end all values are positive. You just need to add your own risk free and standard deviation.  Excel RAND() is same as VBA RND().

```
For i = 1 To 10000
        stockReturn(i) = Exp((RiskFree - 0.5 * StDv ^ 2) + StDv * Application.NormInv(Rnd(), 0, 1)) - 1
Next i
```

Comment: You shouldn't just eliminate `-1`, you should replace it with `/100`.  This will produce an array of returns that are all positive yet more "reasonable".  Just eliminating the `-1` will produce very high numbers.

Comment: @amdopt Yes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need for Returns = normsinv(rand()) * Sigma + Mu for each period.
Then Price = e(Price-1 + Return) for the Monte Carlo price

enjoy ;-)

Comment: This is consistent with my understanding, @demully. What to do if integer is negative?